# Webpack generates big file

Tags: javascript, webpack

Webpack generates too large a file
Webpack 2.x
Webpack experts, i now want to connect `css` in the`js` file
How i include

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import 'angular-ui-notification/dist/angular-ui-notification.min.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';

import '../css/styles.css';
import '../css/custom.css';
import '../css/max-width_767.css';
```

webpack config

```
var glob = require('glob'),
    ngAnnotate = require('ng-annotate-webpack-plugin'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '/application/application.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/build',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new ngAnnotate({
            add: true,
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['babel-preset-es2015'].map(require.resolve)
                },
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|gif|jpg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty'
    }
};
```

That's what i'm getting out of the way, a huge bundle.js file is probably 5 MB with all fonts, pictures, etc.

`bundle.js 5.53 MB 0 [emitted] [big] main`

I just want to concatenate only `css` and output to `bundle.css`

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: First off, what version of webpack are you using, 1.x or 2.x ?

Comment: @PaulKaspriskie webpack version 2.x

Answer (score 0):

You have included [extract-text-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) but you dont actually seem to be using it.

Change here:

```
 {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
 }
```

To something like:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
      loader: "css-loader"
    })
  }
```

Comment: thanks, but no all files will be include to bundle, for example `ERROR in ./img/kitchen-appliance.png
    Module parse failed: /home/jashka/PhpstormProjects/getresto-frontend/img/kitchen-appliance.png Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    (Source code omitted for this binary file)
     @ ./~/css-loader!./css/max-width_767.css 6:33711-33750
`  styles, custom and max width css not include by error

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/342 try the loader syntax but with `ExtractTextPlugin.extract` instead of `use`